# XSL getting ancestors from xsl:key

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML corpus that is structured like this (in reality it contains over 5000 `<deposition>`elements and about 20,000 combined `<seg>` elements):

```
<corpus>
  <deposition id='1'>
    <deposition-title>foo title A<deposition-title>
    <text>
      <seg id='1-A'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='1-B'>some text</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition id='2'>
    <deposition-title>foo title B<deposition-title>
    <text>
      <seg id='2-A' corresp='1-B'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='2-B'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='2-C' corresp='1-A'>some text</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition id='3'>
    <deposition-title>foo title C<deposition-title>
    <text>
      <seg id='3-A'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='3-B' corresp='1-A'>some text</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition id='4'>
    <deposition-title>foo title D<deposition-title>
    <text>
      <seg id='4-A' corresp='2-B'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='4-B' corresp='2-A'>some text</seg>
      <seg id='4-C'>some text</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
  [...]
</corpus>
```

The `seg/@corresp` refers to the `seg/@id>` of other entries. The logic, therefore, is that one can have many `seg/@corresp`'s that match a single `seg/ @id`.

My objective is this in XSL 3.0 : for each `seg[@corresp]` find all other `ancestor::deposition-title`s for `seg` elements that contain the same attribute value.

An example result would be:

Passing `@corresp="1-A"` to a key would return a list of `seg-id`s which share the same `@corresp`: `foo title B, foo title c`

I am now trying to execute this using a `key` in a `xsl:for-each`:

1. use a key to efficiently get all `seg/@id` : 
   `<xsl:key name="segid" match="tei:seg" use="@corresp"/>`
2. apply current `seg/@corresp` to the key (generally `<xsl:value-of select="key('segid', seg/@corresp)">`)

and here is the part I can't figure out in XSL, using a `select` inside a 'for-each' to get the **ancestor** of the `seg` returned by the key:

3. for each `seg/@corresp` output the `deposition-title` siblings of nodes `seg/@corresp` matching it

I hope the above is clear.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Most XSLT Qs are better defined. Edit your Q to show your all required inputs, the required output from those inputs, and your best attempt to solve the problem. Best to also include what versions of XSLT you are restricted to and your working environment (java/saxon, etc, etc). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('segid', seg/@corresp)/ancestor::deposition/deposition-title">
```

Or, maybe this, is everything is always at the same level

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('segid', seg/@corresp)/../../deposition-title">
```

Or maybe this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('segid', seg/@corresp)/../preceding-sibling::deposition-title">
```

Where `..` gets the parent of a node.

I can't help thinking you actually want to do `<xsl:value-of select="key('segid', @id)">` here though (assuming you are currently positioned on a `seg` element.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise we could follow the key with the ancestor axis using ../ Thanks! About your last comment: I am trying to find all other `seg`with the same `@corresp`and then get each relative `deposition-title`.